# How to transfer chaindata from one quorum network to other?

Tags: blockchain, geth, quorum

I have got 6 set of quorum servers, out of which 3 are unreachable. So, now 50% of the network is down and I am unable to bring them up. Now, I am planning to run the setup on new set of servers with old data.

My question is --> How can I export the chaindata from old servers to new servers?
I need a detailed explanation on that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bt if you add new servers as peers. They should automatically sync the block chain from the 3 nodes which are Up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer and I am able to retain the old server data.

This is how I did:
1) I went to a location(any one old server) where chaindata(in .ldb format) is stored. 
2) I zipped the folder in tar.gz format. 
3) Then, I uploaded the tar.gz file in all the new server.
4) So, before starting the geth process in new server, I went to same location where chaindata is stored, I unzipped the file
5) Started the geth process in all new servers
6) All the new servers got synced with the old data